# rsync to check on unsuccessful transfers

Tags: rsync

Have used `rsync` to do a backup but I have noticed some errors during file transfers.  How can I rerun to see what has been unsuccessful.  Have had a go at using `--dry-run` but I am not sure it gives information if a file was not transferred properly.

Comment: Whatever circumstances caused the errors during the initial run of `rsync` may have changed before the subsequent runs, so you can't (n the general case, there are cases where the problems persist).

Comment: I only want to log what was not transferred or transferred with error.